# Problemas para añadir una información entrada por teclado a un ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto

Estoy haciendo un programa de facturación con menú y sub menú  en consola donde utilizo ArrayList para guardar la información mientras funcione el programa, el problema es que no me guarda lo que entra por teclado en el ArrayList, Aquí les dejo el código:

Clase cliente:

```
package programadefacturación;

public class Cliente{

    // Atributos:

    private String NombreCliente ;
    private String NombreEmpresa ;    
    private String TelefonoOCelular ;
    private String CorreoElectronico ;
    private String DireccionResidencia ;    
    private int CedulaORuc ;

    // Construtor con parametros:

    public Cliente (String NombreCliente, String NombreEmpresa, String TelefonoOCelular, String CoorreoElectronico, String DireccionResidencia, int CedulaORuc) {
        this.NombreCliente = NombreCliente ;    
        this.NombreEmpresa = NombreEmpresa ;
        this.TelefonoOCelular = TelefonoOCelular ;
        this.CorreoElectronico = CoorreoElectronico ;
        this.DireccionResidencia = DireccionResidencia ;
        this.CedulaORuc = CedulaORuc ;
    }

    // Constructor sin Parametros:

    public Cliente(){
       this.NombreCliente = "" ;
       this.NombreEmpresa = "" ;
       this.TelefonoOCelular = "" ;
       this.CorreoElectronico = "" ;
       this.DireccionResidencia = "" ;
       this.CedulaORuc = 0 ;
    } 

    Cliente(int CedulaORuc, String NombreClientee, String NombreEmpresae, String TelefonoOCelulare, String DireccionResidenciae) {

    }

    // Metodos set y get:      

    public String getNombreCliente () {
        return NombreCliente ;
    }

    public void setNombreCliente (String NombreCliente) {
        this.NombreCliente = NombreCliente ;
    }

   public String getNombreEmpresa () {
        return NombreEmpresa;
   }

   public void setNombreEmpresa (String NombreEmpresa) {
        this.NombreEmpresa = NombreEmpresa ; 
   }

    public String getTelefonoOCelular () {
        return TelefonoOCelular ;
    }

    public void setTelefonoOCelular (String TelefonoOCelular) {
        this.TelefonoOCelular = TelefonoOCelular ;
    }

    public String getCorreoElectronico() {
        return CorreoElectronico;
    }

    public void setCorreoElectronico(String CorreoElectronico) {
        this.CorreoElectronico = CorreoElectronico;
    }

    public String getDireccionResidencia () {
        return DireccionResidencia ;
    }

    public void setDireccionResidencia (String DireccionResidencia) {
        this.DireccionResidencia = DireccionResidencia ;
    }  

    public int getCedulaORuc () {
        return CedulaORuc ;
    }

    public void setCedulaORuc (int CedulaORuc) {
        this.CedulaORuc = CedulaORuc ;
    }  
}
```

Clase main:

```
package programadefacturación;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProgramaDeFacturación {
    static ArrayList <Cliente> per = new ArrayList <Cliente> () ;
    static Scanner Leer = new Scanner (System.in) ; 
    static Scanner Leer0 = new Scanner (System.in) ;    
    static String NombreClientee, NombreEmpresae, TelefonoOCelulare, CorreoElectronicoe, DireccionResidenciae ; 
    static int CedulaORuc ;
    public static void main (String [] args) {        

           System.out.println("*----------Bienvenido-----------*");
           System.out.println("|--------------al---------------|");
           System.out.println("*-----------programa------------*");
        int seleccionmenu=0;
        do{
            System.out.println("+----------Menu del programa-----------+");
            System.out.println("|--------Seleccione una opción---------|");
            System.out.println("|--------------------------------------|");
            System.out.println("|     1-Cliente   = 1                  |");                    
            System.out.println("|     2-Productos = 2                  |");
            System.out.println("|     3-Factura   = 3                  |");
            System.out.println("|     5-Salir     = 5                  |");
            System.out.println("+--------------------------------------+");
            System.out.println("|Digite la opcion:|"); 
            System.out.println();                          
            seleccionmenu=Leer.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            switch(seleccionmenu){

                case 1:                    
                     int ssmc; // ssmc = SeleccionSubMenuCliente

                     do{ 
                        do{ 
                         System.out.println("|-----------Sub Menu Cliente-----------|");
                         System.out.println("|--------Seleccione una opción---------|");
                         System.out.println("+--------------------------------------+");
                         System.out.println("|     1.1-Agregar Cliente   = 1        |");  
                         System.out.println("|     1.2-Mostrar Cliente   = 2        |");                    
                         System.out.println("|     1.3-Modificar Cliente = 3        |");
                         System.out.println("|     1.4-Buscar Cliente    = 4        |");
                         System.out.println("|     1.5-Eliminar Cliente  = 5        |");
                         System.out.println("|     1.6-Regresar al menu  = 6        |");
                         System.out.println("+--------------------------------------+");
                         System.out.println("|Digite la opcion:|"); 
                         System.out.println();                                   
                         ssmc=Leer.nextInt();
                         System.out.println();
                        }while(ssmc < 1 || ssmc > 6);
                         switch(ssmc){ 

                             case 1:                                 
                                 ingresar(); 
                                 break;          
                             case 2:
                                 System.out.println();
                                 System.out.println("Los clientes registrados son:");
                                 mostrar();
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break;
                             case 3:                               

                                 System.out.println();
                                 break;
                             case 4:
                                 System.out.println("Para buscar el cliente, digite el número de cedula o ruc :");
                                 buscar();
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break; 
                             case 5:
                                 borrar();
                                 break;
                             case 6:
                                 System.out.println("A regresado al menu:");
                                 System.out.println();
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break;
                             default:                                
                                  System.out.println("¡ La selección no es valida !");     
                                  System.out.println("! Ingrese una opción que se encuentre en el sub menu: !");
                                  System.out.println();
                                  System.out.println();                                 
                         }
                     }while(ssmc!=6);           

                    break;
                case 2:
                     int ssmp=0; // ssmp = SeleccionSubMenuProducto
                     do{                         
                         System.out.println("|-----------Sub Menu Producto-----------|");
                         System.out.println("|--------Seleccione una opción----------|");
                         System.out.println("+---------------------------------------+");
                         System.out.println("|     1.1-Agregar Producto   = 1        |");                    
                         System.out.println("|     1.2-Modificar Producto = 2        |");
                         System.out.println("|     1.3-Buscar Producto    = 3        |");
                         System.out.println("|     1.4-Eliminar Prodcuto  = 4        |");
                         System.out.println("|     1.4-Regresar al menu   = 5        |");
                         System.out.println("+--------------------------------------+");
                         System.out.println("|Digite la opcion:|"); 
                         System.out.println();
                         Scanner Teclado1=new Scanner(System.in);            
                         ssmp=Teclado1.nextInt();
                         System.out.println();
                         switch(ssmp){ 

                             case 1:
                                 System.out.println("Ingrese un nuevo producto:");
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break;
                             case 2:
                                 System.out.println("Digite el numero de la opccion del producto a modificar:");
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break;
                             case 3:
                                 System.out.println("Los productos registrados son:");
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break;
                             case 4:
                                 System.out.println("Digite el numero de la opccion del producto a eliminar:");
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break; 
                             case 5:
                                 System.out.println("A regresado al menu:");
                                 System.out.println();
                                 System.out.println();
                                 break;
                             default:                                
                                  System.out.println("¡ La selección no es valida !");     
                                  System.out.println("! Ingrese una opción que se encuentre en el sub menu: !");
                                  System.out.println();
                                  System.out.println();                                 
                         }
                     }while(ssmp!=5);           

                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Usted a salido del progrma");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("¡ La selección no es valida !");     
                    System.out.println("! Ingrese una opción que se encuentre en el menu: !");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
            }
        } while(seleccionmenu!=5);
    }        
    private static void ingresar() {
        int a=-1;
        System.out.println("Digite la cedula/ruc");
        CedulaORuc=Leer.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<per.size();i++){
            if(CedulaORuc==per.get(i).getCedulaORuc()){
                a=0;
            }            
        }
        if(a==-1){
            System.out.println (" Digite nombres y apellidos (N1 N2 A1 A2): ") ;
            NombreClientee = Leer.next () ;
            System.out.println (" Digite el nombre de la empresa : ") ;
            NombreEmpresae = Leer0.next () ;
            System.out.println (" Digite el telefono o celular : ") ;
            TelefonoOCelulare = Leer0.next () ;
            System.out.println (" Digite el correo electronico : ") ;
            CorreoElectronicoe = Leer0.next () ;
            //System.out.println (" Digite la dirección de residencia : ") ;
            //DireccionResidenciae = Leer0.next () ;
            System.out.println(" Se a registrado correctamente ");            
            Cliente ae = new Cliente (CedulaORuc, NombreClientee,NombreEmpresae,TelefonoOCelulare,DireccionResidenciae) ;
            per.add (ae) ;
        }else{
            System.out.println(" La cedula o ruc esta repetido ") ;
            ingresar();
        }
    }

    private static void mostrar() {
        System.out.println("Cedula/Ruc "+" \t "+" Nombres y Apellidos "+" nombre de la empresa "+" telefono o celular "+"correo electronico"+"dirección de residencia");
        for(int i=0;i<per.size();i++){
        System.out.println(per.get(i).getCedulaORuc()+"\t"+per.get(i).getNombreCliente()+per.get(i).getNombreEmpresa()+"\t"+per.get(i).getTelefonoOCelular()+"\t"+per.get(i).getCorreoElectronico()+"\t"+per.get(i).getDireccionResidencia());}
    }

    private static void buscar() {
            int a = -1,CedulaORucc;
            System.out.println("Ingrese el dni");
            System.out.println("Cedula/Ruc "+" \t "+" Nombres y Apellidos "+" nombre de la empresa "+" telefono o celular "+"correo electronico"+"dirección de residencia");
            CedulaORucc=Leer.nextInt();
            for(int i=0;i<per.size();i++){
               if(CedulaORucc==per.get(i).getCedulaORuc()){
                   a=0;
                   System.out.println(per.get(i).getCedulaORuc()+"\t"+per.get(i).getNombreCliente()+per.get(i).getNombreEmpresa()+"\t"+per.get(i).getTelefonoOCelular()+"\t"+per.get(i).getCorreoElectronico()+"\t"+per.get(i).getDireccionResidencia());
               }
            }  
            if(a==-1){
            System.out.println("El dni o ruc no existe, porfavor ingrese un nuevo dato");     
            buscar();
            }    
    }

    private static void borrar() {
        int CedulaORucc ;
        System.out.println("Digite el dni, para eliminaf");
        CedulaORucc=Leer.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<per.size();i++){
            if(CedulaORucc==per.get(i).getCedulaORuc()){
               per.remove(i);
            }
        }
        mostrar();
        }    

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), te recomiendo que pases por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tengas una idea clara del sitio. También te recomiendo que veas [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), cualquier duda que tengas puedes visitar el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Saludos

Comment: Te recomiendo, para que tu problema sea más legible, que elimines las partes del código que no sean directas con tu problema(clase Cliente, etc) y que especifiques cuál es tu error en caso de mostrártelo en consola o si es un comportamiento erróneo que lo comentes bien. Y otra cosa que veo en tu código, no se porque uses 2 Scanner si con uno te basta y te sobra

Comment: Te recomiendo leer un poco más de objetos, ya que programar estructurado en un lenguaje orientado a objetos, no es lo ideal.

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en que el constructor de tu clase Cliente :

```
Cliente ae = new Cliente (CedulaORuc, NombreClientee,NombreEmpresae,TelefonoOCelulare,DireccionResidenciae) ;
```

la cual usas para crear tu objeto Cliente, en realidad no está asignando los atributos. Cambia el método **ingresar()** de tu clase main y coloca esta porción de código:

```
private static void ingresar() {
        int a=-1;
        System.out.println("Digite la cedula/ruc");
        CedulaORuc=Leer.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<per.size();i++){
            if(CedulaORuc==per.get(i).getCedulaORuc()){
                a=0;
            }            
        }
        if(a==-1){
            System.out.println (" Digite nombres y apellidos (N1 N2 A1 A2): ") ;
            NombreClientee = Leer.next () ;
            System.out.println (" Digite el nombre de la empresa : ") ;
            NombreEmpresae = Leer0.next () ;
            System.out.println (" Digite el telefono o celular : ") ;
            TelefonoOCelulare = Leer0.next () ;
            System.out.println (" Digite el correo electronico : ") ;
            CorreoElectronicoe = Leer0.next () ;
            System.out.println(" Se a registrado correctamente ");  
            Cliente ae = new Cliente (NombreClientee,NombreEmpresae,TelefonoOCelulare,CorreoElectronicoe,DireccionResidenciae,CedulaORuc) ;
            System.out.println("NOMBRE = " + ae.getNombreCliente() + "; EMPRESA = " + ae.getNombreEmpresa() + "; CEDULA = " + ae.getCedulaORuc());
            per.add (ae) ; 
        }else{
            System.out.println(" La cedula o ruc esta repetido ") ;
            ingresar();
        }
    }
```

Así, utilizas el constructor correcto, el cual asigna los valores a los atributos de la clase **Cliente**, el cual sería este contructor:

```
Cliente ae = new Cliente (NombreClientee,NombreEmpresae,TelefonoOCelulare,CorreoElectronicoe,DireccionResidenciae,CedulaORuc) ;
```

y para asegurar que cargó, haces una impresión en pantalla de los atributos de los clientes que fueron ingresados, como por ejemnplo:

```
System.out.println("NOMBRE = " + ae.getNombreCliente() + "; EMPRESA = " + ae.getNombreEmpresa() + "; CEDULA = " + ae.getCedulaORuc());
```

Comment: También te recomendaría que cambies la estructuración de tu programa, se me hace que no estás explotando todas las áreas de la programación orientada a objetos. En lugar de encarar con una sentencia do, dentro de otra do, creando un ciclo para preguntar no creo conveniente, yo lo colocaría dentro de métodos, y de acuerdo a la elección voy imprimiendo los menús

Comment: estoy completamente de acuerdo contigo @Carlos y también añadirle un `break` cuando realiza la búsqueda de un Cliente, porque no tiene sentido seguir buscando algo que ya se ha encontrado. Quedaría algo así:
`if(...){
    a = 0;
    break;
}`

Comment: Exactamente, usando IF o SWITCH se ahorraría muchísimo

Comment: muy pocas veces uso este tipo de "interfaces por consola", pero por lo general lo que hago es un `switch` dentro de una función, que en el caso de entrar en el `default` del `switch` llamo a la función recursivamente

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tener mucho cuidado en Java cuando utilices los constructores, debes de llenar el constructor en el orden correcto. Tienes dos constructores en tu clase `Cliente`, en tu código el que llamas cuando añades es el que tiene el siguiente orden: `Cliente(int, String, String, String, String)`, que no tiene nada en el constructor, pero el que en realidad funciona tiene el siguiente orden: `String, String, String, String, String, int`. Así que solo tienes que rellenar el constructor que usas o usar el otro. También te recomiendo añadirle un `break` cuando realiza la búsqueda de un Cliente, porque no tiene sentido seguir buscando algo que ya se ha encontrado. Quedaría algo así:

```
if(CedulaORuc==per.get(i).getCedulaORuc()){
    a = 0;
    break;
}
```

Otra de mis recomendaciones es hacer un `switch` dentro de una función, que en el caso de entrar en el `default` del `switch` llamar la función recursivamente.